# Select an element from element's siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, upload

I have 4 input form element which I want to select an element from the input siblings which its value is changed(ready to upload).but my syntax doesn't work:

**HTML**:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; position: relative; display: inline-block;" class="fileinput-wrapper">
    <div style="background:url(http://localhost/project/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center center" data-provides="fileinput" class="fileinput fileinput-new">
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 130px;background:url(http://localhost/project/assets/images/upload_a_photo.png) no-repeat center center" data-trigger="fileinput" class="fileinput-preview thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1; left: -367.5px; top: 80.9333px;">
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$("input[type=file]").on('change',function(){
    $(this).siblings('.fileinput-preview').css('background','');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[type=file]").on('change',function(){
    $(this).parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background','none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).next('.fileinput-preview').css('background','none');
```